# DXA issue with special character in image names

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.4

In DXA 1.4, when image name is having few special character it is not rendering on the web page. One of the example resolved image name is `Service_&_Support_tcm12-12313.jpg`. In page it is rendering encoded path(`en/media/Service_%26_Support_tcm12-12313.jpg`) but not showing the image. When I have tried to browse the image separately with url `en/media/Service_%26_Support_tcm12-12313.jpg`, it is showing error message `Item '/en/media/Service_&_Support_tcm12-12313.jpg' not found for Localization '12'`. Can anyone suggest if fixed this issue earlier. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two things can be done.Either don't use special characters in the name of image or do explicit encoding for special char in code. I have encountered it once. For you '&' is encoded into %26 in the url.

Answer (score 6):

This was a [known bug](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues/32) in DXA1.2 but was *stated* on that ticket to have been fixed in 1.4.

However, there's [a report](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/17) regards the .Net implementation that this would be fixed in 1.5. The discussion by JordanRobinson is very interesting and may help you towards a workaround but fundamentally you'd be best advised to update the filenames.

Comment: +1 on filenames, but with the large collection of media if you are migrating it then its gonna be a challenge for sure.

Comment: The first issue mentioned was on DXA Java and that one was indeed fixed in DXA 1.4.
Ironically, a similar issue got introduced in DXA.NET 1.3 on Web 8. More specifically, the issue was in CIL 8.1 (used by DXA 1.3 and 1.4). The issue got fixed in CIL 8.2 (used by DXA 1.5).

Comment: Hey Rick, thanks for your comment here. Is there any workaround which I can do(may be temporarily) in my application code? May I use CIL 8.2 without upgrading the whole project to DXA 1.5? This is just to avoid any issue because of last minute upgrade of DXA version. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to use DXA 1.4 with CIL 8.2. You will need some (additional) assembly binding redirects in your web.config. To make it work. Note that upgrade from DXA 1.4 to 1.5 should also be quite easy.

Answer (score 4):

The Query sent to the Broker to get the image will not return anything to your `Model` as the url sent for the request is wrong, hence you will not have it stored in your `BinaryData/en/media/` as well, which leads to stop you not to use correct `src` url as well because there is no such image exists, moreover if any time there is no media returned from Broker, DXA would clean your `BinaryData/media` folder.

In my sugestion, Go with DXA1.5 where this is fixed with CLI 8.2 and if this is really not a good time to do that then please try to use Rick advice on [this](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/17) as also mentioned by Dylan above.

Note: if you know the media url and just want to decode it in your view, you would still not be able to get any image from Binary Data as Broker has not sent it there and Keeping them yourself is really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks Mark & Vikas for your responses. Indeed, shared urls are useful. I have tried, decoding url at application level. But it was not working. I am wondering if there is a quick fix possible at application level, without changing DXA codebase or migrating to a newer version. We have lots of images having special characters in the name.